# Carrierwave file upload fails validation on ActiveRecord Create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

So I have a pretty straight forward implementation of Carrierwave for image upload. I've mounted the uploader on an ActiveRecord Model:

```
class MenuItem < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :description, :menu_id, :name, :active, :photo

    mount_uploader :photo, PhotoUploader

    belongs_to :menu

    before_save :default_values

    validates :name, presence: true
    validates :menu_id, presence: true
    validates :description, length: { maximum: 250 }

    private
       def default_values
         if (self.active.nil?)
           self.active = true
         end
       end  
end
```

The form I'm using combines editing / creating the above MenuItem along with attaching a file:

```
    <%= form_for(@menuitem) do |f| %>
        <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: @menuitem %>

        <%= f.file_field :photo, :id => "photo" %>

        <%= f.label :name %>
        <%= f.text_field :name %>

        <%= f.label :description %>
        <%= f.text_area :description %>

        <%= f.label :active %>
        <%= f.check_box :active, :value => @menuitem.active %>

        <%= f.submit "Save Menu Item", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
        <%= f.submit "Cancel", class: "btn btn-large btn-secondary" %>
    <% end %>
```

Everything works find in the case of Edit / Update.

However, on New / Create I'm getting a validation error on the :photo attribute which simply says "Photo is Invalid". The Uploader definition is vanilla:

```
class PhotoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWaveDirect::Uploader

  after :store, :make_thumbnail

  storage :fog

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  def make_thumbnail(file)
    a = filename.split('/')
    key = store_dir + "/" + a[0] + "/" + model.id.to_s + "_thumb.jpg"

    job = Blitline::Job.new(url)
    job.application_id = ENV['BLITLINE_APPLICATION_ID']

    sf = job.add_function("resize_to_fill", {:height => 100, :width => 100})
    sf.add_save("thumbnail", key, ENV['S3_BUCKET'])

    bs = Blitline.new
    bs.jobs << job   
    res = bs.post_jobs
  end
end
```

And the Controller methods are simple also

```
class MenuItemsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @menuitem = MenuItem.new
    @menuitem.menu_id = params[:menuid]
    @menuitem.active = true
  end

  def create
    @menuitem = MenuItem.new(params[:menu_item])

    if @menuitem.save
        flash[:success] = "Menu Item created!"
        redirect_to menu_path(@menuitem.menu)
    else
        render 'new'
    end    
end
```

I thought maybe the issue was related to the reference to `model.id` in the `store_dir` method of the uploader and that the ID wasn't available since the record hadn't been created yet - but removing that didn't help the issue.

Again, the Edit / Update path that uses the same form and simply calls `menuitem.update_attributes(params[:menu_item])` works fine.

I'm sure there's something obvious I'm missing. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure your upload path has proper permissions to write the file to that directory?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue? I'm running into a similar problem.

Comment: @Blake - I didn't find an elegant solution but implemented a hack to work around the issue. In the `create` method of my controller I'm instantiating a empty model, saving it, and then calling `self.update`

Comment: I think I had the same issue and solved it by adding a simple custom validation. Let me know if you want me to add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix the error by setting up - ur_net_format validation in carrierwave.rb initializer file to false.

**Like so:**

```
ruby
    config.validate_unique_filename = true
    config.validate_filename_format = true
    config.validate_remote_net_url_format = true
```

Hope this helps anyone.

Comment: Wait, what should be set to false?

Answer (score 0):

I've got a suggestion :

Whitelisting formats (in your uploader):

```
  def extension_white_list
   %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've tried that but still get the validation error. The same uploader works in Edit / Update mode with the same image files.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set following in Carrierwave.rb file

```
  config.validate_unique_filename = false
  config.validate_filename_format = false
  config.validate_remote_net_url_format = false # this is important
```

This works for me. Personally, I use carrierwave-aws now as it's much leaner than Fog.

Answer (score 0):

Coming to this very late but I just had the same issue.

What was wrong for me was MiniMagick

I had to strip back my code and call `photo.save!` 
This gave me the error `Avatar Failed to manipulate with MiniMagick`

I removed Minimagick from my uploader file and it worked.
So I need to fix my MiniMagick installation not my code.
Hope this helps someone.